# Filtering fields and sub-fields in Jackson

Tags: json, serialization, filter, field, jackson

For some JSON:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "name":"Test",
  "sub_object":{
    "sub_field_1":1,
    "sub_field_2":2,
    "sub_field_array":[
      {
        "array_field_1":true,
        "array_field_2":false
      },
      {
        "array_field_1":false,
        "array_field_2":true
      }
    ],
    "sub_sub_object":{
      "field_1":"me",
      "field_2":"myself",
      "field_3":"i",
    }
  }
}
```

I want to apply a tree-like list of field names. This could probably be expressed in JSONPath:

```
root
  |-id
  |-sub_object
    |-sub_field_2
    |-sub_field_array
      |-array_field_1
    |-sub_sub_object
```

Then I should get back something like:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "sub_object":{
    "sub_field_2":2,
    "sub_field_array":[
      {
        "array_field_1":true
      },
      {
        "array_field_1":false
      }
    ],
    "sub_sub_object":{
      "field_1":"me",
      "field_2":"myself",
      "field_3":"i",
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that, for some field hierarchy, I want to limit the fields that are output.

I am doing this through a library that has annotated its objects' fields, but I cannot modify the library. It wouldn't really matter if I could because the hierarchy will be on a per-serialization basis. Currently, I am passing the objects into the JsonGenerator's writeObject method, but that returns everything.

Some sub-objects may share field names, so it is not as simple as creating a SimpleBeanPropertyFilter to serialize only a set of names.

Thank you in advance,

John

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom property filter which would take into account the declaring class of the serialised properties.

You should extend the [SimpleBeanPropertyFilter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) and override the `include(PropertyWriter writer)` method. If the given `writer` parameter is an instance of `BeanPropertyWriter` class, you can extract the information about the property origin and apply your custom the filtering logic.

Here is an example of a filter which stores the exclude information in a map of classes and their property names:

```
public class JacksonHierarchyFilter {
    @JsonFilter("filter")
    public static class A {
        public final String field1;

        public A(final String field1) {this.field1 = field1;}
    }

    @JsonFilter("filter")
    public static class B {
        public final String field1;
        public final List<A> list;

        public B(final String field1, final List<A> list) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
    @JsonFilter("filter")
    public static class Foo {
        public final String field1;
        public final List<B> field2;

        public Foo(final String field1, final List<B> field2) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {
        private final Map<Class<?>, Set<String>> excludePropMap;

        public MyFilter(final Map<Class<?>, Set<String>> excludePropMap) {
            this.excludePropMap = excludePropMap;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(final BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(final PropertyWriter writer) {
            if (writer instanceof BeanPropertyWriter) {
                final Class<?> cls = ((BeanPropertyWriter) writer).getMember().getDeclaringClass();
                final Set<String> excludePropSet = excludePropMap.get(cls);
                return excludePropSet == null || !excludePropSet.contains(writer.getName());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final B b = new B("B1", Arrays.asList(new A("A1"), new A("A2")));
        final Foo foo = new Foo("foo", Arrays.asList(b));
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        final Map<Class<?>, Set<String>> excludePropMap =
                Collections.<Class<?>, Set<String>>singletonMap(
                        B.class,
                        Collections.singleton("field1"));
        filters.addFilter("filter", new MyFilter(excludePropMap));
        mapper.setFilters(filters);
        final ObjectWriter objectWriter = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        System.out.println(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(foo));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{
  "field1" : "foo",
  "field2" : [ {
    "list" : [ {
      "field1" : "A1"
    }, {
      "field1" : "A2"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a custom ignore annotation to my serialization. What I ended up was

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface Unsigned {}
```

and

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    @Override
    public String[] findPropertiesToIgnore(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (AnnotatedField field : ac.fields()) {
            if (field.getAnnotated().isAnnotationPresent(Unsigned.class)) {
                result.add(field.getName());
            }
        }
        String[] tmp = super.findPropertiesToIgnore(ac);
        if (tmp != null) {
            result.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmp));
        }
        return result.toArray(new String[] {});
    }
});
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();
```